# How to get ckeditor textarea value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using ckeditor on textarea but i could not get data from it.

Code :

```
<textarea name="DSC" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace('DSC');
  </script>
```

Jquery :

```
var title = $('input[name=TITLE]').val();
    var desc = $('textarea[name=DSC]').text();
    var formdata = 'TITLE='+title+'&DSC='+desc;
```

Comment: var value = CKEDITOR.instances['DSC'].getData()   for the getting the value from ckeditor texted area

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No need for jQuery CKEditor has its own method to get data from converted textarea:

```
var desc = CKEDITOR.instances['DSC'].getData();
```

OR:

```
var desc = CKEDITOR.instances.DSC.getData();
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you!! It took me hours to find this XD

Comment: I am getting "f is undefined" when use these syntax, Anyone faced this and possible solution?

Comment: for everyone using ckeditor 5 you can find the answer here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/saving-data.html. It says that you need to save the created instance of the editor in a separate variable and use it from there.

Comment: For those who might be interested, i made a quick update on this solution for CKEditor 5 (tested in april 2022), as the process has a bit changed since this answer was posted : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361606/how-to-get-ckeditor-textarea-value-using-jquery#answer-71985482

Answer (score 5):

Use id attibute in textarea and use that id in CKeditor instead of textarea's name check bellow

```
<textarea name="textareaname" id="textarea-id"></textarea>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea-id');//use id not name//
var ckValue = CKEDITOR.instances["textarea-id"].getData(); or
var ckValue = CKEDITOR.instances.textarea-id.getData();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [jQuery_Adapter](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter) you may write:

```js
$(function () {
  $('textarea[name="DSC"]').ckeditor();
  $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('ckeditor content: ' + $('textarea[name="DSC"]').val());
  })
});
```

Include files:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.9/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.5.9/adapters/jquery.js"></script>

HTML: 

<textarea name="DSC" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
<button id="btn">Get text</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

alert(CKEDITOR.instances.DSC.getData());

Answer (score 2):

Past Text area id below.

```
 CKEDITOR.instances['Text_Area_Id_Here'].getData();
```

For example, i have text area

```
     <textarea class="form-control" id="Description" name="description" width="100%" height="150" ckeditor="true" maxlength="20000" ismandatory="false">
                                                
                    </textarea>
```

I got value of text area like this

```
 var description = CKEDITOR.instances['Description'].getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
        <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
            This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
        </textarea>
    <button type="button" id="getDataBtn">Get Data</button>

    </form>
     <script>
            // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
            // instance, using default configuration.
         CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

           $(document).ready(function(){

                $("#getDataBtn").click(function(){
                    var editorData= CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
                    alert(" your data is :"+editorData);
                })

           });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//getting data form ckeditor in textarea.

var NodeDataSessionTextarea = {};
jQuery('.class-textarea').each(function(index, el) {
    var editor_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var elevalue = jQuery(this).val();

    // Getting ckeditor instance.
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[editor_id];
    if (editor) {
        editor.on('key', function(e) {
        var self = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                //store data in object with id
                NodeDataSessionTextarea[editor_id] = self.getData();
            }, 10);
        });

        editor.on('afterCommandExec', function(e) {
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                //store data in object with id
                NodeDataSessionTextarea[editor_id] = self.getData();
          }, 10);
        });

        editor.on( 'blur', function() {
            //store data in session
            var nodedataencodetextarea = JSON.stringify(NodeDataSessionTextarea);
            sessionStorage.setItem("NodeDataSessionTextarea", nodedataencodetextarea);
        });
    }
});



//put data in ckeditor.
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[id];
if (editor) {
    editor.setData(getTemplateData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For an update of [Bogdan Kuštan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361606/how-to-get-ckeditor-textarea-value-using-jquery#answer-37361646) using [CKEditor 5](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/development-tools.html#testing-helpers) (tested in may 2022):**

`editor.getData()` is the new way of getting the Data from the editor.

Here is one common example of using it: filling an hidden field on submitting the form.

```
import ClassicEditor from '.../src/ckeditor.js';

ClassicEditor
     .create('#editor-container')
     .then(editor => {
          persistForm(editor);
     };
    
function persistForm(editor)
{  
     document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
          document.querySelector('.hidden-input').value = editor.getData();
     });
}
```

This post is also a reminder for myself later.

Answer (score -2):

You should use `getData()` method to get data from CKEDITOR.

```
<textarea name="DSC" class="materialize-textarea" id="DSC"></textarea>
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace('DSC');
  </script>

//reference the id DSC
var desc = CKEDITOR.instances['DSC'].getData();
```